# Probability that an element will not appear in a Sample of size N drawn from a Set of size N with replacement

Tags: sampling, bootstrap-sampling

The probability that an element of a Set A of size N will not appear in a Sample B of size N drawn with replacement from the aforementioned Set A is 1/3 if I am correct.

But how can we prove this?

I tried to think this over and I arrived to a different conclusion.  I.e. I view the creation of the Sample B as a sequential process through which N slots of Sample B are filled with Replacement from Set A.  Then for a given element E of the original Set A the probability of exclusion from the first slot of Sample B is (N - 1)/N.  The same applies for all the N - 1 remaining slots.  Therefore the probability that E will not appear in any of the slots is the probability that will fail to be included in N independent trials where the probability of non-inclusion is (N - 1)/N. Consequently, the probability of E to be left out once the process of filling the slots of Sample B completes is ( (N - 1)/N ) ^ N.

Your advise will be appreciated.

Comment: It will be $(1-1/N)^N$, which is **not** $1/3$ (but tends to $e^{-1}\simeq 0.36$ when $N\to\infty$; I assume that's why you approximate it with $1/3$?).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you think it should be $1/3$, but in short: it is **not**.

Sampling with replacement independently $m$ times among $N$ disticnt objects gives that the probability of missing a specific object $a$ in every single trial is exactly
$$
\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)\cdot \dots\cdot \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right) = \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^m
$$
as you found; which, for $m=N$, gives
$$
\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^N= \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^m \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} e^{-1}\simeq 0.36
$$
using the well-known definition of the exponential as $e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$.

I assume this is where the $1/3$ comes from: as a (rough) approximation for $e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the other way: I need the [inclusion -exclusion principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), which results in an alternating sum...  When the dust clears you end up with $1-\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1N +{N\choose k}(-\frac1 {N})^k $.  Which equals $(\frac {N-1}N)^N $.  The term $(\frac1N)^k $ appears because it is the probability that  $k $ choices are "positive". ..  the $N\choose k $ because you keep subtracting probabilities (and then adding them, to compensate) of intersections of  $k $ of the $N$ events...

Comment: It is a fallacy -- tempting, but wrong. When events are independent: $\Pr[A\cap B]=\Pr[A]\cdot\Pr[B]$. Here, the events  $A$ "not drawing the element the first trial" and $B$, "not drawing the element the second time" for instance are independent, so $\Pr[A\cap B]=(1-1/N)\cdot(1-1/N)$. What you do is writing $\Pr[A\cap B] = 1-\Pr[\bar{A}\cup \bar{B}] "=" 1- (\Pr[\bar{A}]+\Pr[\bar{B}]) = 1-(1/N+1/N)$. The second "equality" is false.

Comment: You're right.   I forgot to subtract $P (A \cap B) $...